# Как написать правило на yii2 для главной

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте, коллеги.
На yii2 выставил строгое правило для Uri:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true
]
```

Не могу разобраться, как теперь написать правило, чтобы для главной скрыть контроллер. Т.е. сейчас http://domain.ru/site, нужно http://domain.ru/.
Для остальных Uri прописаны такие правила

```
'rules' => [
            '<action:(contact|about|captcha)>' => 'site/<action>',
            '<controller:[-\w]+>/index' => '404',
            '<controller:[-\w]+>' => '<controller>/index',
            '<controller:[-\w]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:[-\w]+>/<action>' => '<controller>',
]
```

Comment: `'request' => [
    'baseUrl' => '',
],` ? ........а  в правилах (rules) **возможно** еще дописать `'/' => 'site/index',`

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно было прописать правило

Answer (score 0):

В настройках добавить

```
'request' => ['baseUrl' => '', ]
```

а в правилах (rules) **возможно** еще дописать

```
'/' => 'site/index',
```